# Driving 100-3000 LED's using AVR microcontroller

Tags: arduino, led, transistors, avr, driver

I want to make a LED display having nearly 3000 LED's. I want to blink these LEDs at a time using AVR uC pins with low logic.

Can anyone tell me how I should connect these LED matrix and which transistor I should go with? Or should I make blocks of 100 LED?

Comment: What's the operating current for this LEDs? Do you want to draw pictures/sentences with these LEDs or light up a room?

Comment: You will need to be a lot more specific than this. Can you give us a schematic? Do all LEDs need to blink at the same time, or do you want individual control over the LEDs? What is the purpose of your design?

Answer (score 4):

With that many LEDs you would either need a really big chip or you could use shift bit registers. If you don't know what those are, they are chips that use 2 pins to write data and 1 pin for the data in question, which means you need 2 pins to control all your shift bit registers, and 1 pin for each 8 pins you control, however, you can daisy chain shift registers together, which means you can use 3 pins to control all your registers if you would like. A more in depth explanation is here: http://bildr.org/2011/02/74hc595/.

I would recommend making an array that matches the aspect ratio of the display you want. If you would like 30x100 display that would work fine. If you don't know how to connect the LEDs you can connect all the negative pins together in each row of the matrix, and all the positive pins in each column. Like the picture below:

[image: LED Matrix]

For adding the shift registers, I would recommend the least amount of daisy chaining possible, so try calculating how many registers you would need, and thus how many pins you would need (2 pins + number of registers). If that is too many pins, try daisy chaining 2 together, so you will have half as many registers. Then you hook them up, you then write a 1 to every row (the negative side of the pin) and a 0 (default) to every column (the positive) which will turn off all the lights. Then for a given LED, you set the column to 1 and the row to 0 and the LED will turn on. You then do this so fast that a viewer can't tell that they are blinking.

All the specifics about how to do this should be in that link above. Also, if you need a reference, look at LED cubes -- they are flat displays like this that are folded a couple times to make them 3D.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice link Jake. Ty